# Call column in dataframe by column index instead of column name - pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I call column in my code using its index in dataframe instead of its name.

For example I have dataframe `df` with columns `a`, `b`, `c`

Instead of calling `df['a']`, can I call it using its column index like `df[1]`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use  [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html?highlight=iloc#pandas.DataFrame.iloc):

```
df.iloc[:, 0]
```

Example:

```
>>> df
   a  b  c
0  1  4  7
1  2  5  8
2  3  6  9

>>> df['a']
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: a, dtype: int64

>>> df.iloc[:, 0]
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Comment: How can apply group by column b with out using column name

Comment: Use `df.groupby(df.columns[1])`.

Answer (score 4):

The [indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) documentation mentions that the indexing operator `[]` is provided more for convenience. The `iloc` and `loc` methods provide more explicit indexing operations on the dataframe.

**Note:** Index has its own connotation in pandas. So when referring to the numeric index (like an array index), it is better to use *interger position* (or just *position*).

```
>>> df
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

>>> df['a']
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

#### Access rows and columns by integer position(s)

`df.iloc[`*row_start_position*`:`*row_end_position*`,` *col_start_position*`:`*col_end_position*`]`

```
>>> df.iloc[0:3, 0:1]
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3

>>> df.iloc[:, 0]  # use of implicit start and end
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

#### Access rows and columns by label(s)

`df.loc[`*row_start_label*`:`*row_end_label*`,` *col_start_label*`:`*col_end_label*`]`

Note: In this example, it just so happens that the row label(s) and the row position(s) are are the same, which are integers `0, 1, 2`.

```
>>>  df.loc[0:2, 'a':'a']
   a
0  1
1  2
2  3

>>> df.loc[:, 'a'] # use of implicit start and end
0    1
1    2
2    3
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

See how to [Query / Select / Slice Data](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/pandas-dataframe-operations/#query) for more details.