# Is there any method to combine multiple rows into one by condition using pandas (not groupby)?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to combine a DataFrames with same column different row into one based on another column in my Excel.
Is there any way to make it possible without using groupby as my data later will need to  iterrows.

**Example is as below:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [16042020, '', '', 17042020,'', '', '', 17042020,'', '', ''],
                    'des': ['I','am', 'happy','I','am', 'a','butterfly','I','am', 'a', 'girl']})

print (df)

**OUTPUT:**

        date        des
0   16042020          I
1                    am
2                 happy
3   17042020          I
4                    am
5                     a
6             butterfly
7   17042020          I
8                    am
9                     a
10                 girl
```

**Expected Output are as below (based on date):**

```
        date        des            Result
0   16042020          I        I am happy
1                    am                  
2                 happy                  
3   17042020          I  I am a butterfly
4                    am                  
5                     a                  
6             butterfly                  
7   17042020          I       I am a girl
8                    am                  
9                     a                  
10                 girl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rather ugly, brute force and perhaps easy to follow solution would be:

```
df['result'] = ""

rows = df.shape[0]
i = 0
while i < rows:
    if df.iloc[i, 0] != "":
        msg = df.iloc[i, 1]
        j = i + 1
        while (j < rows) and (df.iloc[j, 0] == ""):
            msg = msg + " " + df.iloc[j, 1]
            j +=1
        df.iloc[i, 2] = msg
        i = j
```

Don't see any way of doing without looping (implicit or explicit).

Comment: can i know what's the reason to put ```rows = df.shape[0]``` twice yaa?

Comment: sorry, copy paste mistake.

Comment: this solution is work in normal DataFrame but not for my excel, TQ.. xD

Comment: how is the data from excel different from the data in dataframe?

Comment: same data, just that there is no header: Date in Column A, Des in Column B

Comment: strange, it should work as I am not using the column by their names, but by their positions.

Comment: is it because of the  ```NaN```  ? it cannot detect ```""```? because this is the only difference i saw

Comment: i found it, it is because of the  ```NaN``` , thank you so much, it's works!!

Answer (score 1):

How about this, using `' '.join()`, `loc` and `zip`:

```
indexes=df[df.date!=''].index.to_list()+[len(df)]
for i,i1 in zip(indexes,indexes[1:]):
    df.loc[i,'result']=' '.join(df.loc[i:i1-1,'des'])  #same as df.loc[i:i1-1,'des'].str.cat(sep=' ')
df=df.fillna('')
```

Output:

```
df
        date        des            result
0   16042020          I        I am happy
1                    am                  
2                 happy                  
3   17042020          I  I am a butterfly
4                    am                  
5                     a                  
6             butterfly                  
7   17042020          I       I am a girl
8                    am                  
9                     a                  
10                 girl
```

Comment: i got an error: ```raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")```  if i use on ```pd.read_excel``` may i know why?

Comment: is it correct to put like this if my data got no header:: ```df.loc[i,2]=' '.join(df.loc[i:i1-1,2])``` or  ```df.loc[i,2]=' '.join(df.loc[i:i1-1,df[2]])``` ?

Comment: I test it with the dataframe you provide and it works. Maybe it´s because result it's created while looping. Maybe try defining result before the loop: `df['result']=''`, and then make the loop, and that's it. @BBBBBBBB

Comment: This will be the correct in that case: `df.loc[i,2]=' '.join(df.loc[i:i1-1,2])` @BBBBBBBB

Answer (score 0):

if the problem is only with using `iterrows()` after a `groupby` you can do a `reset_index()` which returns a DataFrame from a GroupBy object

or you can use lambda instead

`df['result'] = df.apply(lambda x: " ".join(df[df['date'] == x['date']]['des'].tolist(), axis = 1)`

Comment: can i know if my data don't have header, how do i change the lambda using ```df[0], df[1], df[2]``` ?

Comment: @BBBBBBBB yes you can use iloc, check this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316154/call-column-in-dataframe-by-column-index-instead-of-column-name-pandas

Answer (score 0):

This is more complicated because the data structure has no explicit breaks.   There are repeating dates that act as a break between concatenations.

1. synthesise `foo` as internal column that changes when value is seen in date column
2. concatenate strings based on a break being observed.  Push back into original data frame using `transform()`
3. finally cleanup `result` setting it to empty if there's no value in `date` column

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [16042020, '', '', 17042020,'', '', '', 17042020,'', '', ''],
                    'des': ['I','am', 'happy','I','am', 'a','butterfly','I','am', 'a', 'girl']})

df["result"] = df.assign(foo=df.reset_index()\
          .apply(lambda r: r["index"] if str(r["date"]).strip()!="" else np.NaN, axis=1).fillna(method="ffill"))\
          .groupby("foo").transform(lambda x: " ".join(x))
df.loc[df["date"].str.strip()=="", "result"] = ""
df
```

**output**

```
     date        des            result
 16042020          I        I am happy
                  am                  
               happy                  
 17042020          I  I am a butterfly
                  am                  
                   a                  
           butterfly                  
 17042020          I       I am a girl
                  am                  
                   a                  
                girl
```